# How (i.e. what tool to use) to monitior headers sent by Curl (Cookie problem)

Tags: c++, cookies, curl, libcurl

I am using Curl (libcurl) in a C++ aplication, and am unable to send cookies (I think).

I have Fiddler, TamperData and LiveHTTP Headers installed, but they are only useful for viewing browser traffic, and are (it would seem) unable of monitoring general network traffic on a machine, so when I run my machine, I cant see the header information being sent. However, when I view the page in a browser, when succesfully logged on, I can see that cookie information is being sent.

When running my app, I succesfully log onto the page, when I subsequently, try to fetch another page, the (page) data suggests that I am not logged on - i.e. "state" has somehow being lost.

My C++ code looks alright, so I dont know what is going wrong - this is why I need to:

1. First be able to view my machines network traffic (not just browser traffic) - which (free) tool?
2. Assuming I am using Curl incorrectly, whats wrong with my code? (the cookies are being retrieved and stored ok, it seems they are just not being sent with requests for some reason.

Here is the section of my class that deals with the cookie side of Http requests:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, long(m_timeout));
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);
```

Is there anything wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (the former Ethereal) to view all the network traffic a machine is sending and receiving.

Comment: This seems a bit "too low level" for what I'm looking for. It seems a good tool for a network engineer, but I dont necessarily want to get down to the level of packets and bytes. I just want to be able to look at the HTTP comms and see things like header information, cookies being sent etc. is there a way to setup this otherwise brilliant tool, to show data a bit further up the OSI model (i.e. the application layer as opposed to the network layer - which appears to be the default setting)

Comment: wireshark allows you to "follow a tcp stream" so that you can easily see HTTP comms in a readable fashion

Comment: @f4: care to share how I may "follow a tcp stream"?. This seems to be what I need to do. I just downloaded and installed the package so its pretty new to me. thanks.

Comment: Right-click on any TCP packet - it's in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Sean Carpenter said, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is the right tool to view network traffic. Start a capture and use `http` as a filter to see only HTTP traffic. If you just want to see HTTP requests/responses sent/received by Curl, set the CURL_VERBOSE option and look at stderr: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L)`.
2. I believe you are using Curl correctly. Compile and run the following (complete) example; you will see that, *the second time* you run it (when `cookies.txt` exists) cookies are sent to the server.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode success;
    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    int m_timeout = 15;

    if ((curl = curl_easy_init()) == NULL) {
        perror("curl_easy_init");
        return 1;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, long(m_timeout));
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1L);

    if ((success = curl_easy_perform(curl)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", "curl_easy_perform", errbuf);
        return 1;
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```